# Martingale and sequential correlation

Tags: math, statistics, probability, correlation

Suppose that X,Y, and Z are Gaussian random variables. Now, suppose that we are computing and partial correlation with N sequential samples. That is, after N samples if we have a sequence of N partial coefficients. Is this sequence a martingale?

Comment: Hi. It would help if you could edit your question to add a bit more details. What definition of a martingale do you know?